# Android: Customized NumberPikcer can't roll

Tags: android, scrollview, numberpicker

this is my custom numberpicker

public class CustomNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

```
public CustomNumberPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p != null)
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Because this numberpicker is in a scrollview, and it's hard to roll the number,
so i override onInterceptTouchEvent(). This customized method works well on TimePicker.
But after customing, the numberpicker can not roll,but the uparrow and downarrow works well.
Is there anyone who has solution to this problem? Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: I use the same override method to the linearlayout out of numberpicker，and it works well, also I add a onTouchEvent to the layout to prevent misoperation.